# Express bitwise negation (`NOT`, bitwise complement) using other bitwise operations?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, ones-complement, bitwise-not

I am writing an algorithm in a limited language where the bitwise operators at my disposal are

- `AND`: `&`
- `OR`: `|`
- `XOR`: `^`
- `SRL`: `<<` (shift left)
- `SLL`: `>>` (shift right)

I realized I need to be able to take the bitwise complement of an integer, commonly denoted `~x` in other languages.

**Could I somehow express `~x`, using only the `{&, |, ^, <<, >>}` operators?**

I would try to just implement this operator in the language’s compiler, but it seems like a very challenging task. I would much rather do some dirty hack to express `NOT x` without `~`.

Comment: Well, I suppose I could just convert the value to an array of binary values, flip them in a loop and then convert the array back into an integer… I wish there were a simpler solution though

Comment: XOR with -1?  (Or whatever numeric constant has an all-1-bits representation on your system.)

Comment: @jasonharper a simple XOR with an all-1-bits number is indeed the solution. What a shame, apparently my brain is toast. Thanks!

Comment: Please add your comment as an actual answer so I can select it as the accepted answer.